# Sharepoint online list view formatting DefaultHoverView using forEach

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, json, view-formatting

I am using Sharepoint list JSON view-formatting and want a list of names to each show their live persona card on hover. I can get this to work for just one name, but when I use forEach I cannot get the hover action to work. Is this a bug/not yet possible or am I doing something wrong?

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideListHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "float": "left",
      "flex-direction": "column",
      "width": "320px",
      "margin-right": "15px",
      "margin-bottom": "15px",
      "border-style": "solid"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "forEach": "person in [$an6t]",
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "a",
            "txtContent": "[$person.title]",
            "defaultHoverField": "[$person]",
            "style": {
              "cursor": "pointer",
              "box-sizing": "border-box",
              "color": "black",
              "text-decoration": "none"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following JSON format using forEach:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "personIterator in @currentField",
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "width": "32px",
        "height": "32px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "border-radius": "50%",
        "margin": "2px",
        "display": "=if(loopIndex('personIterator') >= 3, 'none', '')"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "img",
          "attributes": {
            "src": "='/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + [$personIterator.email]",
            "title": "[$personIterator.title]"
          },
          "style": {
            "position": "relative",
            "top": "50%",
            "left": "50%",
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "auto",
            "margin-left": "-50%",
            "margin-top": "-50%",
            "display": "=if(length(@currentField) > 3 && loopIndex('personIterator') >= 2, 'none', '')"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "attributes": {
            "title": "=join(@currentField.title, ', ')",
            "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
          },
          "style": {
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%",
            "text-align": "center",
            "line-height": "30px",
            "font-size": "14px",
            "display": "=if(length(@currentField) > 3 && loopIndex('personIterator') == 2, '', 'none')"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "span",
              "txtContent": "='+' + toString(length(@currentField) - (2))"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
    "defaultHoverField": "[$personIterator]"
    }
  ]
}
```

Reference:

https://thechriskent.com/2019/04/04/generate-list-formatting-elements-in-a-loop-using-foreach/

Comment: This works when just applied to one column using row formatting, however I'm using view formatting for the whole row and when this code is applied to that it doesn't work (will update code in question now!)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't change my code and now it works, it must've been patched since I asked.